# How to load an (contentful) asset in Picasso (Android)

Tags: android, image, assets, picasso, contentful

The datatype for images I receive from Contentful (by using a library called Vault) is an asset. I want to display the image in an ImageView but I can't load an asset in Picasso. Arguments can be Uri, File, Int or String.

Is there any way to get one of these arguments from the asset I received?

Comment: what type of asset it is ?

Comment: The asset properties are:

sys (Sys), fields.title (Text), fields.description (Text), fields.file (File), fields.file.filename (Symbol), fields.file.contentType (Symbol), fields.file.url (Symbol), fields.file.details (Object), fields.file.details.size (Number).

Comment: kindly show the code for the asset you received

Comment: I manage to solve the problem myself. Since I'm using the library Vault, I should have looked into the code. Turns out Vault has a method called toUrl() which returns an url.

Comment: glad you have your problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vault has a method for assets called toUrl(). This will return a Url which can be used by Picasso

Comment: You can also take a look at the source of one of our sample apps: https://github.com/contentful/gallery-app-android/blob/2bc73baa4373b185f426ad9a3107cd2d898a7b99/app/src/main/java/gallery/templates/contentful/gallery/SlideImageAdapter.java#L32 This shows you how to load the image of an asset from Contentful into picasso.